# Github Actions Docker when using reusable workflow can't get credentials from provider

Tags: github-actions

In my called workflow, I'm using the official aws credentials action ([Link to marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/configure-aws-credentials-for-github-actions)) and the the official Docker Login action ([Link to Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/docker-login)) to log into my ecr, but the docker login action throws this error:

```
    Error: Could not load credentials from any providers
```

It will work perfectly if I run it in the caller workflow, but on the called workflow it fails every time. I suspect that it has something to do with how it's storing the env variables, but I haven't been able to nail it down yet. The second AWS credential action is to assume the role where the ecr repo is located.

Any insight would be appreciated

Here is my caller workflow:

```
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    uses: <Owner>/<repo>/.github/workflows/called_workflow.yml@master
    secrets: inherit
    with:
        environment: dev
        aws_account_number: 123456789123
        aws_region: us-east-1
        docker_image_name: thisisanimage
        aws_profile_name: bestprofile
        aws_role_arn: arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/<rolename>
```

and here is the called workflow

```
jobs:
  build-and_push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
 - name: Configure AWS Credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
    with:
      aws-region: <region>
      role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::<account1>:role/<assumedrole1>
      role-skip-session-tagging: true
      role-duration-seconds: 1200
      mask-aws-account-id: false
 - name: Configure other AWS Credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
    with:
      aws-region: <region>
      role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::<account2>:role/<assumedrole2>
      role-skip-session-tagging: true
      role-duration-seconds: 1200
      mask-aws-account-id: false
      role-chaining: true
  - name: Login to Docker
    uses: docker/login-action@v2
    with:
      registry: <account2>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<repository>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are populating your credentials from secrets? Can you provide more details on both workflows. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows

Comment: updated question with the sanitized code for both workflows

Comment: Looks correct, I was thinking maybe you were missing the `secrets: inherit`. I wonder if you need to explicitly pass the values from env to the docker login? https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/blob/35d8f9588bf190a9a7fda3411cd548fb8234bee2/index.js#L165-L171C24

Comment: Swapped to OIDC credentials. Same issue. updated question to reflect current setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the called workflow AWS_PROFILE was being set and this was the cause of issue.